# How can I implement a proper counter bean with EJB 3.0?

Tags: java, jpa, concurrency, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

[EDIT] This question is "how do I do atomic changes to entity beans with EJB 3 and JPA 2.0". Should be simple, right?

I tried to fix my code based on the answers I got so far. I'm using JBoss 6.0.0M2 with Hypersonic (just download it and call run.bat).

My test case: Create 3 threads and call one of the `testCounterMitLock*()` 500 times in a loop. So a successful test should print "Anzahl eingetragene Zeilen: 1500" (3*500).

I tried:

```
        CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1);
        manager.lock(ct, LockModeType.WRITE);
        int wert = ct.getWert();
```

Obviously doesn't work because a different thread can change the value in the database before the lock is applied. So I try to fix that:

```
        CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1);
        manager.lock(ct, LockModeType.WRITE);
        manager.refresh (ct);
        int wert = ct.getWert();
```

The `refresh()` should give me the current value and the implicit query should also make sure the object gets locked now. No such luck. Let's try with JPA 2.0:

```
        CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1, LockModeType.WRITE);
        int wert = ct.getWert();
```

That also doesn't work. Maybe the lock isn't enough?

```
        CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
        int wert = ct.getWert();
```

Uhm ... doesn't work either! One last desperate attempt:

```
        CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
        manager.flush();
        manager.refresh (ct);
        int wert = ct.getWert();
```

Okay ... can anyone explain why nothing works? I'm out of ideas.

[EDIT2] PS: To add insult to injury, this is the last output of the last running thread:

```
commit/rollback: 441/62
```

(441+62 = 503)...

Here is the complete code. First the bean:

```
package server.kap15;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Stateful
public class CounterTestBean implements CounterTestRemote, SessionSynchronization {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JavaEE")
    EntityManager manager;

    private int commit = 0;

    private int rollback = 0;

    public void initDatenbank() {
        manager.createNamedQuery("CounterTest.deleteAll").executeUpdate();
        manager.createNamedQuery("TestTabelle.deleteAll").executeUpdate();
        CounterTestVersion ct = new CounterTestVersion();
        ct.setNr(1);
        ct.setVersion(1);
        ct.setWert(1);
        manager.persist(ct);
    }

    public boolean testCounterOhneLock() {
        try {
            CounterTest ct = manager.find(CounterTest.class, 1);
            int wert = ct.getWert();
            ct.setWert(wert + 1);
            TestTabelle tt = new TestTabelle();
            tt.setNr(wert);
            manager.persist(tt);
            manager.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean testCounterMitLock() {
        try {
            CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1);
            manager.lock(ct, LockModeType.WRITE);
            int wert = ct.getWert();
            ct.setWert(wert + 1);
            TestTabelle tt = new TestTabelle();
            tt.setNr(wert);
            manager.persist(tt);
            manager.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean testCounterMitLock2() {
        try {
            CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1);
            manager.lock(ct, LockModeType.WRITE);
            manager.refresh (ct);
            int wert = ct.getWert();
            ct.setWert(wert + 1);
            TestTabelle tt = new TestTabelle();
            tt.setNr(wert);
            manager.persist(tt);
            manager.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean testCounterMitLock3() {
        try {
            CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1, LockModeType.WRITE);
            int wert = ct.getWert();
            ct.setWert(wert + 1);
            TestTabelle tt = new TestTabelle();
            tt.setNr(wert);
            manager.persist(tt);
            manager.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean testCounterMitLock4() {
        try {
            CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            int wert = ct.getWert();
            ct.setWert(wert + 1);
            TestTabelle tt = new TestTabelle();
            tt.setNr(wert);
            manager.persist(tt);
            manager.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean testCounterMitLock5() {
        try {
            CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            manager.flush();
            manager.refresh (ct);
            int wert = ct.getWert();
            ct.setWert(wert + 1);
            TestTabelle tt = new TestTabelle();
            tt.setNr(wert);
            manager.persist(tt);
            manager.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean testCounterMitVersion() {
        try {
            CounterTestVersion ctv = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1);
            int wert = ctv.getWert();
            ctv.setWert(wert + 1);
            manager.flush();
            TestTabelle tt = new TestTabelle();
            tt.setNr(wert);
            manager.persist(tt);
            manager.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            System.out.println(">>> Versionskonflikt !");
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public long anzTestZeilen() {
        Query query = manager.createNamedQuery("TestTabelle.anzZeilen");
        Long anzahl = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
        return anzahl;
    }

    public void afterBegin() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    }

    public void beforeCompletion() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    }

    public void afterCompletion(boolean committed) throws EJBException,
    RemoteException {
        if (committed)
            commit++;
        else
            rollback++;
        System.out.println("commit/rollback: " + commit + "/" + rollback);
    }
}
```

The remote interface:

```
package server.kap15;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface CounterTestRemote {
    public void initDatenbank();

    public boolean testCounterOhneLock();

    public boolean testCounterMitLock();
    public boolean testCounterMitLock2();
    public boolean testCounterMitLock3();
    public boolean testCounterMitLock4();
    public boolean testCounterMitLock5();

    public boolean testCounterMitVersion();

    public long anzTestZeilen();
}
```

The persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="JavaEE">
        <jta-data-source>java:DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The test client:

```
package client.kap15;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
import server.kap15.CounterTestRemote;

public class CounterTestMitLock extends Thread {
    CounterTestRemote ctr;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            testMitLock();
            testMitLock2();
            testMitLock3();
            testMitLock4();
            testMitLock5();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    static int N = 3;
    static CounterThread[] ct = new CounterThread[N];

    private static void testMitLock () throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("--- Counter Test MIT Lock ----------------------");
        System.out.println("Testinstanzen erzeugen...");
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            ct[i] = new CounterThreadMitLock();

        runTest ();
    }

    private static void testMitLock2 () throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("--- Counter Test MIT Lock2 ----------------------");
        System.out.println("Testinstanzen erzeugen...");
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            ct[i] = new CounterThreadMitLock2();

        runTest ();
    }

    private static void testMitLock3 () throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("--- Counter Test MIT Lock3 ----------------------");
        System.out.println("Testinstanzen erzeugen...");
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            ct[i] = new CounterThreadMitLock3();

        runTest ();
    }

    private static void testMitLock4 () throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("--- Counter Test MIT Lock4 ----------------------");
        System.out.println("Testinstanzen erzeugen...");
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            ct[i] = new CounterThreadMitLock4();

        runTest ();
    }

    private static void testMitLock5 () throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("--- Counter Test MIT Lock5 ----------------------");
        System.out.println("Testinstanzen erzeugen...");
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            ct[i] = new CounterThreadMitLock5();

        runTest ();
    }

    private static void runTest () throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Datenbank initialisieren...");
        ct[0].ctr.initDatenbank();

        System.out.println("Test durchführen...");
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            ct[i].start();

        System.out.println("Auf Ende warten...");
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            ct[i].join();

        System.out.println("Anzahl eingetragene Zeilen: " + ct[0].ctr.anzTestZeilen());
    }

    private static CounterTestRemote verbinden() {
        try {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);

            Object ref = ctx.lookup("CounterTestBean/remote");
            CounterTestRemote ctr = (CounterTestRemote) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref, CounterTestRemote.class);

            return ctr;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - NamingException!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public abstract static class CounterThread extends Thread
    {
        protected CounterTestRemote ctr;

        public CounterThread ()
        {
            this.ctr = verbinden ();
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                test ();
        }

        public abstract void test ();
    }

    public static class CounterThreadMitLock extends CounterThread
    {
        @Override
        public void test ()
        {
            this.ctr.testCounterMitLock();
        }

    }

    public static class CounterThreadMitLock2 extends CounterThread
    {
        @Override
        public void test ()
        {
            this.ctr.testCounterMitLock2();
        }

    }

    public static class CounterThreadMitLock3 extends CounterThread
    {
        @Override
        public void test ()
        {
            this.ctr.testCounterMitLock3();
        }

    }

    public static class CounterThreadMitLock4 extends CounterThread
    {
        @Override
        public void test ()
        {
            this.ctr.testCounterMitLock4();
        }

    }

    public static class CounterThreadMitLock5 extends CounterThread
    {
        @Override
        public void test ()
        {
            this.ctr.testCounterMitLock5();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since none of the locking modes worked, I tried [ewernli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217862/ewernli)'s solution with a manual `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. That gave an interesting exception: "Unexpected token FOR". So I looked at the database.

JBoss is installed with [Hypersonic](http://hsqldb.org/) 1.8 (HSQLDB) as the default which doesn't support row locking. Dear JBoss developers: A JPA implementation is supposed to throw an exception when a locking mode isn't supported.

So I added an Oracle datasource and changed my persistence.xml. After that, two tests work:

```
        CounterTestVersion ct = manager.find(CounterTestVersion.class, 1, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
        int wert = ct.getWert();
```

and

```
    Query query = manager.createNativeQuery ("select * from COUNTER_TEST where NR = 1 for update", CounterTestVersion.class);
    CounterTestVersion ct = (CounterTestVersion)query.getSingleResult ();
    int wert = ct.getWert ()+1;
```

which is interesting. It should work with `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`, too. In this case, I see this error in the log:

```
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
```

This happens in the call `manager.find()`. I can't see why the two behave differently in the load-phase. Maybe a bug in JBoss or Hibernate.

Comment: Ah ok! Glad to get a confirmation that `select for update` and `pessimistic_write` work in the general case.

Comment: +1 by the way. I hope you reported the odd behavior with HSQLDB as a bug :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a few remarks:

- You are currently using optimistic locking but I don't see any `@Version` field on your entity. I don't think this can work.
- If you want the counter to be incremented 1500 times, don't use optimistic locking (you don't want any update to be rejected with an `OptimisticLockingException`) but pessimistic locking.
- Swallowing `Throwable` is really wrong, you want the container to do his job (but I guess you know that).

<strike>So, here I would use this instead:</strike>

```
manager.lock(ct, LockModeType.READ);
```

And remove the `catch (Throwable t)`.

**Update:** I can't test this right now but I would use something like this (the rest of the code is unchanged):

```
public boolean testCounterWithLock() {
    CounterTest ct = manager.find(CounterTest.class, 1);
    manager.lock(ct, LockModeType.READ);
    int counter = ct.getCounter();
    ct.setCounter(counter + 1);
    manager.flush();
    return true;
}
```

> I really doubt that this will work. First of all, a read lock doesn't prevent other threads to update the row. Secondly, another thread can update the row between the find() and the getCounter()

You're right, I went too fast and the above is certainly not a solution and @ewernli is also right, JPA 1.0 doesn't have support for pessimistic locking strategies, you would have to rely on the database for that (and use the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` semantics). Somehow, I managed to forgot about that and made a big confusion with the READ mode. My bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

> I think you must use LockModeType.WRITE but maybe you can use em.refresh() after the lock() to make sure the entity isn't stale?

When using `LockModeType.WRITE`, the field of the entity annotated with `@Version` is added in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` and the concurrency check is done during the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE COUNTERTEST SET COUNTER = ?, OPT_LOCK = ? 
WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (OPT_LOCK = ?))
```

If the `WHERE` clause fails to match a record (because another thread has already updated the entity), then the persistence provider will throw an `OptimisticLockException`.

In other words, refreshing the entity after the `lock()` won't change anything, another thread could still flush the same entity while another is modifying the counter. The only way to deal with optimistic locking in an automated way would be to implement a retry mechanism.

But when the `flush()` throws a [`PersitenceException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html) (except instances of [`NoResultException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html) and [`NonUniqueResultException`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/NonUniqueResultException.html)), the current transaction is marked for rollback and can thus not be used for transactional purposes. So each retry must be performed using a new transaction. In a statless bean, you could make recursive remote calls but I don't think that this makes sense in a stateful bean so you would have to handle that from the client side.

At the end, and that's not very satisfying, the less worse way to deal with this in JPA 1.0 is in my opinion to get a lock with a SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Comment: It is a book example but the book doesn't contain a solution. It just gives three examples how you shouldn't do it. So my question is: Can you post a correct version that will always work? The performance should be as good as possible of course.

Comment: Re your update: I really doubt that this will work. First of all, a read lock doesn't prevent other threads to update the row. Secondly, another thread can update the row between the `find()` and the `getCounter()`.

Comment: I think you must use LockModeType.WRITE but maybe you can use `em.refresh()` after the `lock()` to make sure the entity isn't stale?

Comment: @Aaron You're right about the `LockModeType.READ`, I went too fast.

Comment: I think the only way to have it correct is to acquire an exclusive write lock when you read the entity, which JPA 1.0 does not permits. The problem can mabye be mitigated with `lock` followed by `flush` or `refresh` to the force the acquisition of a lock as quickly as possible, but it still doesn't prevent the issue altogether.

Comment: The source of the problem is that the default database doesn't support locking. See my answer :-)

Comment: @Aaron That's why I wanted to see the generated SQL (to execute it against the DB) :) Good to know, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Even with `LockModeType.READ` or `LockModeType.WRITE`, JPA 1.0 does support only **optimistic locking**. The lock acquisitions can still be deferred to commit time, hence the problem you experienced.

From [JPA 2.0 concurrency and locking](http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and):

> PA 1.0 only supported Optimistic read
>   or Optimistic write locking.  JPA 2.0
>   supports Optimistic and Pessimistic
>   locking

Other resources: [EJB3 performance](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/ejb/ejb3_performance.htm) and [Pessimist Locking with JPA](http://www.funofmath.com/weblog/2008/03/implementation-of-pessimistic-locking.html)

To have real **pessimistic locking** with JPA 1.0, you will need to rely on the database or implementation specific extension. E.g.:

JPA 2.0 (Something similar is possible with Hibernate API)

```
Account acc = em.find( Account.class, id, PESSIMISTIC );
```

JPA 1.0

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * ... FOR UPDATE"); // works with most db
Account acc = (Account) query.getSingleResult();
```

At least, that's what I've finally use, because `lock` didn't worked as expected.

( Note: You could also implement a retry logic when an optimistic exception happens. But it's complicated because the transactions are managed by the app. server. You would need to use `@TRANSACTION_NEW` to pause the current transaction and start a new one, etc. ... too complicated I think! )

Comment: Re stateful: In the example, they counted the failures in the catch clause. counter field -> stateful.

Comment: Nitpick: PESSIMISTIC is not a valid `LockModeType` http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html

Comment: @Aaron Strange. The only one you haven't tested is PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT. Who knows, maybe that's the right one :)

Comment: That's interesting. It doesn't work but with PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT, all but the first transaction fail in `manager.flush()`!

Comment: @Aaron Really strange. To me `testCounterMitLock4` sounds like the correct one. A few more idea to troubleshoot: (1) try with native query `SELECT * FOR UPDATE` to make sure there isn't something wrong somewhere else (2) enable show SQL and see if there is something of interest (3) if you use MySQL make sure you use InnoDB tables (4) if you use Hibernate implementation, give a try to `query.setLockMode ( ... , LockMode.UPGRADE);`

Comment: Correction: That might have been a glitch. But now I get 18/485 as output (i.e. 503 transactions instead of 500).

Comment: Concurrent access to SFSB are normally not allowed. How come that you don't get a `ConcurrentAccessException` http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/ejb/ConcurrentAccessException.html ? Is the count correct in database?

Comment: The source of the problem is that the default database doesn't support locking. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what you do with the return value from testCounterWithLock. My guess is that you are getting Optimistic locking failures and the return value is false sometimes.

Optimstic locking is a reasonable model when clashes are likely to be infrequent in practice, and the caller can reasonbly redo the work. So if you are getting optimistic failures you could just retry.

Alternatively, use a pessimistic locking model, this locks the row in the database at the point you read. You can do that my adding a LockMode of Pessimistic to your call to find(). Use of pessimistic locking needs to be done with care, all too easy to get bad concurrency and/or deadlocks.

Comment: Can you give an example how to "adding a LockMode of Pessimistic to your call to find()"?

Comment: I couldn't find a version of `find()` which supports a `LockMode`. This is JPA 2.0, right?

Comment: I tried with JPA 2.0 but it doesn't work. Can you have a look at my edits of the question, please?